# Compare two columns for matches using vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I would really appreciate if somebody has an idea on how to do the following task faster. I have a list of names in column A and I want to see if any of those names show up in column C. The code below has work great when I test it with 500 names. But when I use my full data that has around 3000 values in column A and 150000 in column C I'm not sure if it's running correctly because it has been close to two hours and it has not finished.

```
Sub compare_cols122()

    Dim NameList As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Set NameList = Excel.Worksheets("Names")


    LastRow = NameList.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        For j = 2 To LastRow
            If NameList.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, NameList.Cells(j, 3).Value, NameList.Cells(i, 1).Value, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    NameList.Cells(j, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    NameList.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    Exit For
                Else
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean to say your code takes too much time,,,?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your code sped up by loading the data into arrays and performing the comparison with them:

```
Sub compare_cols122()

    Dim NameList As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set NameList = Excel.Worksheets("Names")

    Dim rngNames As Range
    Set rngNames = Range("A1", Range("A1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp))
    Dim varNames As Variant
    varNames = rngNames.Value2

    Dim rngData As Range
    Set rngData = Range("C1", Range("C1").Offset(Rows.Count - 1).End(xlUp))
    Dim varData As Variant
    varData = rngData.Value2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For i = LBound(varNames) + 1 To UBound(varNames)
        For j = LBound(varData) + 1 To UBound(varData)
            If varNames(i, 1) <> "" Then
                If InStr(1, varData(j, 1), varNames(i, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    NameList.Cells(j, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    NameList.Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    Exit For
                Else
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Note that swapping the inner and outer loops will only slow down the search irrespective of how rare the matches are.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the data from the cells over and over is inefficient.

Use an array(s) to load all the values into.

Then do what you need to do to the array.

Put the values back in the cells when everything is done.